# SSRS parameters basics with ODBC Connection

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, odbc, ssrs-2008

I have built a report using visual studio 2012, but I cant pass a parameter into it.

I have set up the report parameter called cust, and it gets its values from a dataset.

I have set up a seperate dataset which has a field called cus and i set a query parameter called customer to equal the cust parameter. In the query I have:

```
where cus = (@customer)
```

I get an error:

> column "customer" does not exist

Can someone confirm where I am going wrong?

Edit: Connection type is an ODBC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I am completely rewriting this because of the ODBC clarification.

Change your @Cust to a ?

```
Select Cus, FirstName, LastName, otherDataYouMayNeed
From Table Name
Where (cus = ?)
```

Then set the parameter name to ' `?` '

Click on the Parameters Section of the dataset you are working on then make sure you change the parameter name value to a `?`

This should work for your ODBC.

(Make sure you make your parameter datatype to match the datatype of the "customer")

Comment: Hi,to confirm i have one dataset pulling customers from a table and using it to fill up the parameters dropdown. This parameter is called cust and can be seen under report data->Parameters. for the dataset under the parameters section of the properties i have an entry called customer that has the value [@cust]. in the query for the dataset i have "where cus= @customer".  when click ok i get a define qeury parameters box which i click ok on. then it tells me there is no column called customer.

Comment: it only appears to be when conencting via ODBC to a postgres data source. if i connect to an sql server datasource, parameters work ok

Comment: @user3050116 when you are connected to the ODBC you have tested your connection and everything works (are you using an odbc driver for the connection)? Does the table on the ODBC have the exact name that you are trying to pull? Finally, from what I know and have read the syntax for an odbc is slightly different so I would check that as well.

Comment: HI,yes i am using an ODBC connection. If instead of using a parameter i set the query to eqaul a certain customer, it all works fine

Comment: @user3050116 So I changed the Answer. I am unfamiliar with working with an ODBC connection into SSRS but I read this somewhere, just can't place my finger on it right now. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi, thats seems to works!!

I assume if i want more i keep setting them as ? and it takes them in the order i have set them in the parameters list of the data set?

Comment: @user3050116 Yup, you just keep adding ' ? '  and you are correct in assuming they get called in the same order as your parameters in the parameter section. p.s. dont forget to mark it as answered if it is the best answer. Thanks!